# How to change widget view in background service

Tags: android-widget

I have created widget. I am trying to update the widget in background each 5 seconds (For testing purpose 5 second). But it is not getting update.Is any mistake on my code.

**Provider class**

```
package com.widget.widgetapplication;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Random;

public class MyWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    private int randomNumber = 0;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Receive", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Update", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // Get all ids
        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context,
                MyWidget.class);
        int[] allWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);
        for (int widgetId : allWidgetIds) {
            // create some random data
            randomNumber = new Random().nextInt(100);

            RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                    R.layout.widget_layout);
            Log.w("WidgetExample", String.valueOf(randomNumber));
            // Set the text
            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.time, String.valueOf(randomNumber));

            appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(widgetId, R.id.time);
            // Register an onClickListener
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyWidget.class);
            intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
            intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                    0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.watch, pendingIntent);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
        }
    }
}
```

**widget info xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minHeight="100dp"
    android:minWidth="100dp"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/analog_watch"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="5000">
</appwidget-provide
```

**Registered receiver in manifest**

```
<receiver android:name=".MyWidget">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/widget_info"/>
        </receiver>
```

**Widget layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <AnalogClock
        android:id="@+id/watch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Time is : "
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

YES. you are doing it wrong.

the minimum available value for updatePeriodMillis is 30min (1800000 millis).

[official document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProviderInfo.html#updatePeriodMillis) :

> Note: Updates requested with updatePeriodMillis will not be delivered more than once every 30 minutes.